Is it possible to get the id passed to a route in laravel if there is no model with that id using the missing function?
I am using model binding in a route and I want to handle the case where an id is missing from the database. According to the documentation you can use the missing method to handle this possibility. Is it possible to get the id that was passed to the route?
Using the following code I cannot find an attribute with the id when testing the route /document/idThatDoesNotExist:
Route::middleware(['throttle:document'])
    ->resource('document', DocumentController::class)
    ->only(['show'])
    ->missing(function (Request $request) {
    $request->dd();
});

As a temporary solution I have used the following piece of code to get the id but I wonder if there is a better way:
$document_id = preg_replace("/.*\/document\/(.*)/", "$1", $request->getRequestUri());


you can pull route parameter values out of the $request object by using the route('param_name', 'default_value') method, in your case:
Route::middleware(['throttle:document'])
    ->resource('document', DocumentController::class)
    ->only(['show'])
    ->missing(function (Request $request) {
        dd($request->route('document'));
    });

